# Generate dummy traffic over OpenVPN link

Tags: python, openvpn, traffic

I'm trying to generate some dummy traffic that is sent over an existing OpenVPN link.

I can ping some public IP over the OpenVPN link, but that's not enough traffic for my tests.

How could I generate some (e.g. 5MB) dummy traffic? I do not have access in any other way on the OpenVPN server. The dummy traffic should be initiated by the OpenVPN client and does not have to contain any specific data.

I was considering creating a blob of random data and using python to send it to the port on the server, where OpenVPN is listening.

I don't want to rely on an active internet connection, so I don't want to simply download some file off the web.

OpenVPN 2.4.0 on two Debian systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use `ping` with `-s` (size of packet) and `-i` (interval) option

2) Use `bwping`

3) Use `iperf3` on both hosts

4) Use `scp` to copy a large file from one host to another, for example to `/dev/null`

5) Use `nc` to pipe `/dev/null` from one host to the other, with an `pv -L` on the sending side for rate limiting

...

Comment: The `ping` solution with the packet size seems pretty viable.. the other options aren't suitable for me, as I the only connection I have to the server is the OpenVPN connection.

Comment: They might be interesting for someone else testing out two servers connected via OpenVPN, however. Which is why I included them.